# How do I refresh discord Oauth2 access token using refresh token?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord.js

I am using discord Oauth2 on my website.

This is my code:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let info = document.getElementById('info');

if (params.has('code')) {
    let code = params.get('code');

    fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
        method  : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body    : new URLSearchParams({
            client_id     : '################',
            client_secret : '######################',
            grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
            code          : code,
            redirect_uri  : 'http://127.0.0.1:5501/public/'
        })
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(function(res) {
            setInterval(() => {
                fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token/revoke', {
                    method  : 'POST',
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    body    : new URLSearchParams({
                        client_id     : '############',
                        client_secret : '##################3',
                        grant_type    : 'refresh_token',
                        refresh_token : res.refresh_token
                    })
                });
            }, 10000);
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(function(res) {
            fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
                headers : {
                    authorization : `${res.token_type} ${res.access_token}`
                }
            })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then(function(res) {
                    const username = res.username;
                    info.textContent = username;
                });
        });
}
```

And Whenever I refresh my page the refresh token disappears.

But this code gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Just before I fetch the user/@me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the `then` handler just before

```
.then((res) => res.json())
```

You are not returning the promise given to you by `fetch`, which is required when chaining promises. Here `undefined` is getting resolved because `fetch` is inside setInterval callback.

What you can do is - return a promise inside the `then` handler and resolve that promise to `fetch` call after your desired timeout / interval (since fetch returns a promise).

e.g. In your then handler, you can do this -

```
.then(function(res) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    resolve(fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token/revoke', {
        method  : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body : new URLSearchParams({
            client_id     : '############',
            client_secret : '##################3',
            grant_type    : 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token : res.refresh_token
        })
    }))
  }, 10000);
 })
})
```

However, do note that promises are resolved only once. So effectively, setInterval will only resolve the promise only once for you.